# How to use groupby in python for multiple columns?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, pivot, aggregate

have a df with values :

```
name   numb         exam       marks   

tom     2546        math         25     

tom     2546        science      25 

tom     2546        env         25 

mark    2547        math        15 

mark    2547        env         10


sam    2548         env         18
```

how to use groupby and form values?

```
name   numb       total_exams_attended       total_maths_exam_attended  total_marks_scored_in_maths  total_marks_scored
 
tom    2546           3                               1                       25                          75
mark   2547           2                               1                       15                          25
sam    2548           1                               0                                                   18
```

tried this :

```
df=df.groupby(['name']).agg({'total_exams_attended': 'count','total_marks_scored': lambda x: sum(x == True)})
```

But got stuck in total_marks_scored_in_maths  column. how to do groupby / aggregate for only particular column values like maths here

Answer (score 0):

Consider `pivot_table` with some column name manipulation due to hierarchy and aggreate name:

```
pivot_df = df.pivot_table(index='name', columns='exam', values='marks', aggfunc=['count', 'sum'], 
                          margins=True, margins_name='total')

pivot_df.columns = [i+'_'+j.replace('count', 'exams_attended').replace('sum', 'marks_scored') 
                            for i, j in zip(pivot_df.columns.get_level_values(1),
                                            pivot_df.columns.get_level_values(0))]
```

Output

```
pivot_df
#        env_exams_attended  math_exams_attended  science_exams_attended  total_exams_attended  env_marks_scored  math_marks_scored  science_marks_scored  total_marks_scored
# name
# mark                  1.0                  1.0                     0.0                     2              10.0               15.0                   0.0                  25
# sam                   1.0                  0.0                     0.0                     1              18.0                0.0                   0.0                  18
# tom                   1.0                  1.0                     1.0                     3              25.0               25.0                  25.0                  75
# total                 3.0                  2.0                     1.0                     6              53.0               40.0                  25.0                 118
```

Should you need to filter down to math and total columns use `.loc`:

```
math_pvt_df = pivot_df.loc[df['name'].unique(),
                           ["math_exams_attended", "total_exams_attended", 
                            "math_marks_scored", "total_marks_scored"]]

math_pvt_df
#       math_exams_attended  total_exams_attended  math_marks_scored  total_marks_scored
# name
# mark                  1.0                     2               15.0                  25
# sam                   0.0                     1                0.0                  18
# tom                   1.0                     3               25.0                  75
```